# How to add arrow at end of a line in Plotly line chart R

Tags: r, plotly

I have a line chart that groups data into about 10 lines in one chart. I am trying to add simple arrows at the end of each line.

Here is my code as of now. As you'll see, I'm trying to use annotations to add these arrows, but I'm failing to add them accurately. They should each point from the second to last point in their line, to the last point (making it seem like one continuous arrow-line from the start to the end).

```
  chart <- plot_ly(homeChartData, x = ~val2, y = ~val1, group = ~NAME, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', marker = list(symbol = c("","triangle-right"), size = c(1,10)), 
                          color = ~NAME, colors = colorz, showlegend = TRUE)   %>% 
           layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y, title = paste("Progress")) 
           
         
         chart
```

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. What I did was I set mode to "lines+markers" so that I could get markers. Then in the body of plot_ly() I set "marker = list(symbol = c("","triangle-right"), size = c(1,10)). Essentially I just said "forget the first marker. Give it no symbol and give it a size of 1 so it cannot be seen." Then I set the other marker to be a "triangle-right" symbol and set it to a larger size. I edited the above for clarity.

add_annotations() was not necessary.

Hope this helps someone else.